# Как убрать ошибку 'event' is already declared in the upper scope on line ...?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

```
element.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.beginSliding);
//...
private beginSliding(event: any) {
//...
  target.onpointermove = (event: any) => {
    //...
  }
}
```

ошибка на втором (event: any)
можно ли её убрать без Disable no-shadow for this line ?

Comment: просто переименуй параметр

Comment: точно! почему в коммент? ответ же)